Subclass supplier not a valid supplier for class
I have a get or create method in a library I'm using that looks like this:
A getOrCreateA( Function< U,A > ) {}

B extends A
And yet, in my code, I take in a Function<U,B> but I am unable to feed it into the method above. Could someone explain why? I can see why this wouldn't work for a list, but surely anything that creates a B, by it's nature creates an A.
Alternatively, could anyone suggest an alternative solution?
My use case is essentially a type specific getOrCreate:
public B getOrCreate_b(U ignore, Function<U,B> constructor) {
    A return_val = ignore.getOrCreate_a(constructor); //<- error
    if (return_val instanceof B) 
        return (B)return_val;
    else 
        return constructor.apply(ignore);
}

(Yes, I'm aware this won't actually store B if the function returns A, it's dealt with elsewhere.)

Java doesn't know that the second argument of a Function is inherently solely 'producing'. The function makes Bs and never reads them. No method in a Function implementation has a B as parameter; it shows up only in the return type.
But, that's today. Maybe tomorrow someone adds that (Nobody will; java is backwards compatible, but, the lang spec doesn't demand this and has no way for Function itself to declare that its second type param cannot possibly show up in a consuming role).
Thus, java applies the usual rules to the generics which is that they are invariant. If a List<Number> is needed, only a List<Number> will do; neither a List<Integer> nor a List<Object> will work, even though Integer extends Number. After all:
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> nums = ints;
Double d = 5.5;
nums.add(d);
int x = ints.get(0);

Try to grok that code and you will understand why generics are invariant where basic types (not inside the <>) are covariant (covariant = a subtype is as good as one of its supertypes).
The fix is that the getOrCreateA function is broken. It should have been defined as follows:
public <U, A> A getOrCreate(U v, Function<? super U,? extends A> constructor) {

Note the ? super and ? extends syntax which says: The first arg is contravariant, the second is covariant: Only consume the first, only produce the second. Which works out, as that's exactly how functions actually 'work'. If that had been the signature, your code would have worked. That trick (Function<? super I, ? extends O>) is all over e.g. the collections APIs of java itself, because there's no reason not to do it.
If you can't change the underlying function you can't fix this without dipping into uglycasting and getting a lot of warnings. That tends to happen when you use badly written, broken libraries. You should not use such libraries or tell its authors to fix their stuff.

Thankyou, fantastic answer. To be fair i'm extending a pre-existing code base so while not ideal for me, makes sense. Is there any specific ugly hacks I might be willing to put up with. Currently the best idea I have is to change my method signature to Function<U,A> cast the result to B, leave some comments and hope because the method signature is private, it will be fine.

@slitbodmod This answer already told you: use Function<? super U, ? extends A>.  Is that what you mean?  You can also convert a Function<U, B> to a Function<U, A> with function::apply.
